# Create a subdomain and shift wordpress into this subdomain

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I have a task to create a sub domain and then copy the whole wordpress site from main domain to sub domain. I have the main directory caroline-baxter.com and wordpress is installed on it. Now i want to copy this [caroline-baxter](http://caroline-baxter.com) whole wordpress site into its sub domain [caroline-baxter/test](http://www.caroline-baxter.com/test/). I have followed the following steps to be done:

1. Copied all the files and folders into the test folder
2. Import the caroline-baxter database
3. Changes the urls in the sql file.
4. Created a new database and import it from  the caroline-baxter database
5. Changed the database name in wp-config.php (I am using same user name and password)

The test site is not working (as you can see: [test site](http://www.caroline-baxter.com/test/)). Here you can also see that http://www.caroline-baxter.com/test/wp-admin redirects to the http://www.caroline-baxter.com/wp-admin. I can not sort out the problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you ever changed .htaccess to fit the subdomain?

Comment: take a look at this article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress it appears your urls haven't changed

Comment: @Tom: I have just followed the above mentioned steps. Would you please guide me what will have to do with .htaccess to fit the sub domain?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried all the options found here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble , especially this section - http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble#Site_URL_Redirecting ? If so, it might be an issue with your server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi probably you need to change this -

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dir/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

dir is the sub folder name, if it's not in a root domain.

Hope it helps.